# Python : No module webkit on windows 10

Tags: python, webkit, gtk

I am working on a Python application on Windows10 in which I want to use Webkit module from Python. I am getting an error as no module named webkit. I have installed pygtk and python, but I cannot find anything for webkit. Any ideas?

Code :

```
import os
import urlparse
import webkit
import gtk


view = webkit.WebView()

sw = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
sw.add(view)

win = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
win.add(sw)
win.resize(1080,1920)
win.show_all()
uri = 'resources/football.html'
uri = os.path.realpath(uri)
uri = urlparse.ParseResult('file', '', uri, '', '', '')
uri = urlparse.urlunparse(uri)

view.load_uri(uri)

gtk.main()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly pygtk is a dead project and you shouldn't use it; PyGObject is the maintained bindings.

Secondly only a very old version of WebKitGtk supports Windows that is terribly insecure and unmaintained so you shouldn't use it.

So sadly WebKitGtk does not support Windows.

Comment: Thank you. Any other suggestions to get an embedded browser running? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know of any other reasonable solutions for Gtk. If your code is not security sensitive (offline only data) then old WebKitGtk can work...